# printing output on new line in Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a file in app.js which is being passed to handlebars for displaying the output.

The data in the file is of the format abc,Siva,Naga,def, etc.., that is every name is separated by comma(,).But,I want the data to be printed on each line separately i.e

abc

Siva

Naga

Def

I tried using various approaches like using the helpers in handle bars , 
 syntax but none of them works.Reason might be handlebars treat all the data as a single object rather than array of objects.

Is there any way to fix this issue.

Comment: i *think* it's **<br />** and not **</br>** :)

Comment: Provide some more information. What you've tried so far. Can you create a jsfiddle and post the code here?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to work fine. [Here is a working demo](http://jsbin.com/hawehi/1/edit?html,js,output).

Here is the relevant code

```
var data = {
  line: 'abc,Siva,Naga,def'
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('lineBreak', function(line, delim) {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(line.split(delim).join('<br/>'));
});

{{lineBreak line ','}}
```

Comment: I guess there is something missing on my side which I am trying to figure out.
When I ran the code using the working demo, I get the following error -
TypeError: Object #<ExpressHandlebars> has no method 'registerHelper'

Does this mean that I cant use registerHelper here?

Comment: Sometimes jsbin fails to load ember and the other deps. In those cases I just go to the full screen demo http://jsbin.com/hawehi/1

Comment: Im running this in node.js and not jsbin. is there any prerequisite for using handlebar helpers apart from using npm install??